# HTTPS to HTTP Redirect Not Working In ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, aws-application-load-balancer

I have an EC2 running some software and I've been using Certbot but we need to move away to ACM.

For ACM to work, we need Cloudfront -> ALB -> TG -> EC2. The EC2 is running on HTTP so I want the user to hit cloudfront with HTTPS and the ALB to do the translation of HTTPS to HTTP target group.

**However when I go to the ALB domain (or cloudfront) I just get `Connection Refused`.**

I followed this guide [How to redirect HTTPS to HTTP on ELB Application Load Balancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55988233/how-to-redirect-https-to-http-on-elb-application-load-balancer) - which said simply to create an ALB with https listener and tg with port 80 which is what i did.

I have a HTTPS Listener on the ALB:

[image: pgadmin load balancer]

I have the target group set to port 80

[image: target group settings]

Comment: Does https on alb work? Can you access your website when you use alb's url?

Comment: No, this is the problem. I navigate to the alb domain and it has connection refused @Marcin

Comment: Did you setup SG on ALB?

Comment: @Marcin good question. I have checked and all ports are open to all ips on the alb, ingress and egress

Comment: So only https does not work? If you try http (may need to add http listener)?

Comment: @Marcin yeah if i change everything to HTTP, cloudfront and alb, the full process works. But we do not want HTTP for security, hence i am trying to enable https at the ALB end

Comment: Yes I understand, just want to narrow down the issue. Did you get the SSL cert properly verifified for your own domain (not AWS domain)?

Comment: @Marcin yep we use the SSL cert elsewhere in our infra so it's legit. The target group health check is also happy, so does seem to me to be between ALB and TG

Comment: Try to switch route53 (or anything else you use for DNS) directly as an alias to your ALB. Also check SG of the ALB for ingress IP adress of the Cloudfront https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json. Or open it temporarily  to the world.

Comment: Maybe if you run `curl -i https://<alb-url>` you will get some more info?